# Different Between rpc (remote procedure call) and webservices

Tags: json, jax-ws, rpc

I wanna know the basic different between rpc and webservices. which should be prefer.
I wanna choose between json-rpc and jax-ws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Web service**:

Web services are typically application programming interfaces (API) or Web APIs that are accessed via Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) and executed on a remote system hosting the requested services. Web services tend to fall into one of two camps: big Web services and RESTful Web services.

**RPC**:

Remote Procedure Calls. It enables a system to make calls to programs such as NFS across the network transparently, enabling each system to interpret the calls as if they were local. In this case, it would make exported filesystems appear as thought they were local.

**Which one is preferable**:

RPC would be used only for internal/in-house servers where you have influence on both the client and server code. The most frequent case is to forward services which only exist on a few machines. For example, to minimize the number of licenses or support overhead needed by forwarding requests to a central machine, or to provide access to software that is other operating system specific (eg, Linux programs that need to use an old program only available on SGIs.) The other case is to reduce startup costs.

We can identify two major classes of Web services, REST-compliant Web services, in which the primary purpose of the service is to manipulate XML representations of Web resources using a uniform set of "stateless" operations; and arbitrary Web services, in which the service may expose an arbitrary set of operations

May it will be helpful to you...

Comment: in  web service each time i change in my method i have to regenerate client? what if changes more frequently.

Comment: i think for that you could use [link](www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFacade.aspx) which would provide a unified interface to all of the different versions of the web service that the client needs to interact with.

Comment: plz explain for this example ... i made client and exposed a someMethod (par x,par y ). now i added on more parameter to someMethod(par x,par y,par z). in this case i have to regenerate my client. its there any solution for this in web service